# How to filter map in dynamodb on aws console?

Tags: filter, amazon-dynamodb

I am have a simple table like below on DybamoDB

What I need:

i am trying to filter  tools_type attribute which is MAP Type , i want to filter antivirus of this MAP column, but filter option shows only type as string,number,boolean only...how can i filter only antivirus and its value in below example

Note: I need to do filter on awsdynamodb console

What I tried:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filtering MAP or LIST in web console is not possible. Please use SDK or REST api instead.

Here is an example of applying a filter on a MAP attribute using Python SDK:

[image]

```
>>> import boto3
>>> from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
>>> dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
>>> table = dynamodb.Table('example-ddb')
>>> data = table.scan(
...     FilterExpression=Attr('tools_type.antivirus').eq('yes')
... )
>>> data['Items']
[{'pk': '2', 'tools_type': {'antivirus': 'yes'}}]
```

Comment: Can you give any example for API pls

Comment: Are you asking an example for `scan` or `query`?

Comment: mine it little table at max 500 items will be there, i dont mind if its a scan or query...i need some python restapi snippet to filter that value antiviurs and its value from above example

Comment: @asp I've added an example in my answer.

Comment: thank you very much.. it helps, but can you tell me in my example i defined all tools types in single map ,from modelling perspective is that correct?  would your example work on same ?

Comment: @asp I don't understand your modelling tbh. Can you explain more in detail?

Comment: sorry, let me put this way.. you created  antivirus , yes as 1 item and antivirus ,no as item 2 in your example. But if you see my screenshot i have defined all tools types in single attribute like  `{    "antivirus" : { "S" : "no" },    "backup" : { "S" : "yes" },    "desktopcentral" : { "S" : "yes" },    "graylog" : { "S" : "yes" }}` so i need to filter only antivirus and its value this attribute. So your code works for this scenario as well ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217828/discussion-between-asp-and-jellycsc).